# Проблема с записью SQL данных в ассоциативный массив PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, появилась большая проблема, но не хочу тратить Ваше время и описать проблему лишь на данном этапе:

Есть одна функция и в ней var_dump результата переобразования SQL=>Массив.
Дело в том, что мне нужна только конкретная запись в БД, но не выходит её получить. Пробовал с while - результат так же ничего, просто чисто ничего не выводит. Также пробовал var_dump с while но без указания конкретной ячейки.

Вот нынешний код функции(с while):

```
function Redirect($user_id,$sql_connection){
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `owner_id` = ".$user_id." ";
    $sql_response = mysql_query($sql_query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_response)){        
        var_dump($row);
    }
}
```

Пробовал так без while:

```
function Redirect($user_id,$sql_connection){
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `owner_id` = ".$user_id." ";
    $sql_response = mysql_query($sql_query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_response); // в этом коде убран только while!
    var_dump($row);

}
```

Вот рабочий вариант, но тут выводит все записи, а мне надо лишь одна:

```
function Redirect($user_id,$sql_connection){
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `links`"; // убран поиск записи по WHERE
    $sql_response = mysql_query($sql_query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_response)){        
        var_dump($row);
    }
}
```

Думаю, проблема в мелочи, но сейчас вообще никак не выходит, а проблема большая.

Comment: Во втором варианте попробуйте обработайте ошибку в mysql_query(). Выглядит все нормально, вариант должен работать - возможно со стороны MySQL какая-то ошибка.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `owner_id` = ".$user_id." ";
```

Данный запрос может ничего не возвращать(если нет проблем с коннектом) по трем причинам.

1. Подставляемый `$user_id` отсутствует в таблице. Проверьте, есть ли он там.
2. Поле `owner_id` - не числовое. В таком случае необходимо поправить запрос таким образом(апострофы вокруг `".$user_id."`):

   ```
   $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `owner_id` = '".$user_id."' ";
   ```
3. В `$user_id` какая то неведомая ересь, которую БД не способна распознать.

Напишите второй строчкой в функции `var_dump($sql_query)`, скопируйте вывод и выполните запрос прямо в БД, через `phpmyadmin` например.

Несколько советов:

1. Используйте `mysqli` вместо `mysql`. расширение `mysql` считается устаревшим и более не поддерживается.
2. Посмотреть, сколько строк попало в выборку можно функцией [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-num-rows.php)
3. После выполнения запроса контролируйте ошибки. [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-error.php)